# why moving float to xmm0 lead to output 0

Tags: assembly, floating-point, printf, abi

Want to print floating-point value via printf in assembly

```
    segment .data
float_fmt   db  "%f", 0xa, 0
fp  dd  1.1

    segment .text
    global  main
    extern  printf
main:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    lea rdi, [float_fmt]
    movss   xmm0, [fp]
    mov eax, 1
    call    printf
    leave
    ret
```

I want to print single-precision floating-point number(dd, 4 bytes),
however, printf prints 0.000000
Changing

```
fp dd 1.1
```

to

```
fp dq 1.1 ; store double-precision floating-point(dq, 8 bytes)
```

and

```
movss xmm0, [fp]
```

to

```
movsd xmm0, [fp] ; move double-precision floating-point (8 bytes)
```

solves the problem.
Could you explain why?

Comment: floats varargs are promoted to double.

Comment: In this case how to print exactly floats(4 bytes) with format string "%f" not doubles?
Should one always cast float to double before passing in xmm* registers?

Comment: @BulatM.: yes, you can't tell printf to interpret an arg as a float, only double or long double, so you should use cvtss2sd instead of movss.

Comment: Is double 4 bytes in size and long double 8 bytes in size?

Comment: double is 8 bytes, long double 10 bytes (if IIRC)